# How do you perform a resumable upload to a google docs collection? Namely using Java and g-data library

Tags: google-docs-api, gdata-api, google-drive-api

I've got a working system to upload to the default root using resumable uploads and I've been able to make the meta data in a collection but I need to be able to do this type of upload straight to a collection or sub collection.

My main problem is the url, there's no defined example of a straight upload path to a collection?

I assumed that it would be like:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/folder%3A[folder_id]/contents
```

considering that the typical upload path is similar except without the upload/create-session part?

Answer (score 0):

In a folder entry, look for a link like this:

```
<link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#resumable-create-media"
    type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full"/>
```

The href is what you need to send to to create the file in that folder.

p.s. Have you considered using the new [Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive)? It has this funcitonality and is considerably better to use.

Comment: Firstly this isn't techically correct but not helpful... One I know how to do a resume able media upload which, but how do you do one directly to a collection or sub collection on Google Docs. Also sadly no, I've looked into the Drive SDK, the problem is that it's designed to work through 'installing' the app through the chrome web store and requires permissions on the drive to be able to upload in file, which I find limiting for my app,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was originally correct and the URL I provided was correct for uploading but the function I created for generating the URL was missing out the / between feeds and upload